# Get data type of Mongoose fields

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to get the data types of the fields in my mongoose schema. Here is my mockup schema:

```
const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  nested: [{
    nr: {
      type: Number,
    },
  }],
});
```

I want to get a string value representing the data type of each field. `name === 'string'` `nested[0].nr === 'number'` and so on.

I have tried `TestSchema.paths.name.instance` but it doesn’t work for the `nested` field (and it isn’t documented so probably not a good solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `schema.path('path')` which returns a SchemaType object.

```
TestSchema.path('nested').schema.paths.nr.instance
```

This line would return 'Number'.
Check out examples at [What is a SchemaType?](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work for the `nested` field in my schema.

Comment: I have edited my answer. schema.path returns a configuration object for mongoose with numerous properties. Nested objects live within the 'paths' proprety.